# Reading a file after writing on it

Tags: ruby

I am doing [exercise 16](https://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex16.html) at `learnrubythehardway.org`. 
The name of a file is passed as argument to the following script, which asks the user to write three lines to the file:

```
filename = ARGV.first

puts "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'w+')

puts "Now I am going to ask you for three lines."
print "line 1: "
line1 = $stdin.gets.chomp
print "line 2: "
line2 = $stdin.gets.chomp
print "line 3: "
line3 = $stdin.gets.chomp

puts "I am going to write these to the file."
target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")

puts "Here is your new file:"
print target.read

puts "And finally we close it"
target.close
```

Just before closing the file I would like the user be given the opportunity to see the content of the new file, however that part of the code is not processed. Why is that?

Comment: Define "not processed"

Comment: I do not see printed on screen the content of the file

Comment: But this is something else entirely, isn't it? I assure you, it is being processed just fine. Evident from the fact that your program doesn't crash.

Comment: It's like you come to a doctor and declare "I have lupus". No, you most likely don't, you just made an incorrect conclusion based on incomplete data. Wording and precision is important. As are basic debugging skills. This case was simple enough that we were able to just _see_ it. But if you had a more complicated scenario, no [mcve] and no triage, then you'd be left with a few downvotes instead of an answer.

Comment: The above is to say: "it is very useful to be able to do some basic investigation by yourself". You won't be able to always rely on stackoverflow for fixing bugs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [rewind](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-i-rewind) the file, if you want to read what you have just written.

```
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")

target.rewind
target.read
```

#### Bonus content

Use `puts`, it writes the newline for you.

```
target.puts(line3)
```